# Why does this return the wrong value?

Tags: python

When `get_class_average(["Alice","Lloyd"])` is entered, the answer should be `85.85` but instead, it returns `91.15`.

```
lloyd = {  
    "name": "Lloyd",  
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],  
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],  
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]  
}  
alice = {    
    "name": "Alice",   
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],    
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],    
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]  
}   
tyler = {   
    "name": "Tyler",    
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],   
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],  
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]   
}   

def average(numbers):   
    total = sum(numbers)   
    total = float(total)    
    tot = total / len(numbers)    
    return tot    
def get_average(student):    
    homework = average(student["homework"])    
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])    
    tests = average(student["tests"])  
    homework = homework * 0.1   
    quizzes = quizzes * 0.3   
    tests = tests * 0.6  
    return tests+quizzes+homework    
def get_letter_grade(score):   
    if score >= 90:  
        return "A"  
    elif score >= 80:  
        return "B"  
    elif score >= 70:  
        return "C"  
    elif score >= 60:  
        return "D"  
    else:  
        return "F"  

print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))  

def get_class_average(students):  
    results = []  
    for x in students:  
        savg = get_average(x)  
        results.append(savg)  
        return average(results)
```

Comment: You should indent your code if you need our help.

Comment: Sorry... I will edit now

Comment: Will be surprised if this code executes even after indentation

Comment: Or did you mean get_class_average([alice,lloyd])  ?

Comment: I cannot do that. It is entered by the codecademy website so...

Comment: Extremely unlike. Your code wil refue to run as I have already mentioned.

Comment: Changed it but codecademy still doesn't accept it. I guess this is a codecademy bug and not a python issue. So I should delete this question. Thank you for helping me bugfix!

Answer (score 0):

`get_average` needs to be passed a `dict` and not the name of the student. So I'm amazed that this runs at all:

Note your calling of `get_class_average(["Alice","Lloyd"])` - passing a list of strings. Each element is passed unmodified to `get_average()`

Probably you should say `get_class_average([alice, lloyd])`

Comment: I cannot do so as it is entered by codecademy. I believe it is supposed to match the key on the dict at the top

Comment: This will not run in Python.

Comment: I don't know...  My teacher is making me do it on codecademy, which is on py 2.7. I normally use py 3.4 but my teacher says I have to use 2.7  in class. Freaking syntax differences

Comment: Define a function called get_class_average that has one argument students. You can expect students to be a list containing your three students.
First, make an empty list called results.
For each student item in the class list, calculate get_average(student) and then call results.append() with that result.
Finally, return the result of calling average() with results.

Comment: Well, all of us are exactly saying that. You need to pass a list of *students* not a list of *strings*. And this is Python version independent.

Comment: I changed it to pass a list but codecademy is still saying that it is incorrect...

Comment: Changed it but codecademy still doesn't accept it. I guess this is a codecademy bug and not a python issue. So I should delete this question. Thank you for helping me bugfix!

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns 85.85 for me - when the correct indentation is used and `get_class_average()` is passed a list of dictionaries instead of a list of strings.

`get_class_average(["Alice","Lloyd"])` should actually cause an exception because you are passing the student as a string, not a dictionary. Change your code to:

```
print get_class_average([alice, lloyd])
```

and you should see `85.85` printed - once you fix the indentation of the final `return` statement in `get_class_average()` like this:

```
def get_class_average(students):  
    results = []  
    for x in students:  
        savg = get_average(x)  
        results.append(savg)  
    return average(results)
```

Your code has the `return` statement indented within the body of the for loop. As a result only *one* average is calculated (for `alice`) before ther function returns, and the result is therefore `91.15`.

I suggest that you fix that one line to deindent the `return` statement, and resubmit your code to code academy.

Comment: Changed it but codecademy still doesn't accept it. I guess this is a codecademy bug and not a python issue. So I should delete this question. Thank you for helping me bugfix!

Comment: No, it's not a code academy bug. The bug is in your code where the `return` statement is indented too far. Because of that the for loop executes only once before the function returns and the average is not properly calculated. If your code was working in code academy but just producing the wrong value, simply change the single line to _deindent_ the `return` statement in `get_class_average()` and it _should_ work.

Comment: Just to clarify, code academy _is_ calling your `get_class_average()` with a list of dictionaries. This must be true because you get a (albeit incorrect) result of 91.15.  It's just that you wrote that it was being called with a list of strings that is confusing everyone.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation issue but codecademy still won't accept it. So, I have filed a bug report and this thread should be closed by the mods.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

def get_class_average (students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append (get_average (student))
    return average(results)